# How to cover multiple test cases in one automation script

Tags: c#, testing, automation, case

In many cases I find it redundant to write a script for each little test case. How can I use Microsoft VS to write a script that can test more than one test case and report the result to each associated test case in Microsoft MTM without running each test cases separately. Say, for example, I have a yes/No/Cancel dialog that pops up and there is a test case to verify for each of the three cases. All three cases can be verified in one script. Would it be possible to associate each test case to the same script and get the results reported to each one by running the script only once?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MSTest.exe or VSTest.console.exe to run TestMethods via command line. One can call MSTest.exe or VSTest.console.exe in batch file.

Assign user defined testcategory attribute to group your tests. Please refer [Defining Test Categories to Group Your Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286595.aspx). For Example

```
[TestCategory("Nightly"),
 TestCategory("Weekly"), 
 TestCategory("ShoppingCart"), 
TestMethod()]
public Void DebitTest()
{
}

[TestCategory("Nightly"),
 TestCategory("Weekly"), 
 TestCategory("ShoppingCart"), 
TestMethod()]
public Void CreditTest()
{
}

[TestCategory("Nightly"),
 TestCategory("Daily"), 
 TestCategory("ShoppingCart"), 
TestMethod()]
public Void BVTTest1()
{
}

[TestCategory("Nightly"),
 TestCategory("Daily"), 
 TestCategory("ShoppingCart"), 
TestMethod()]
public Void BVTTest2()
{
}
```

Running Tests via VSTest.Console.exe group by TestCategory

```
Vstest.console.exe myTestProject.dll /TestCaseFilter:”TestCategory=Nightly"
```

Running Tests by MSTest.exe group by Test Category

```
mstest /testcontainer:MyTestprojectName.dll /category:"Nightly"
mstest /testcontainer:MyTestprojectName.dll /category:"Daily"
```

Please refer [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx) for more command line options in this topic.